# Angular 8 - How to iterate a Json in a function?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I created this function in the component.ts

```
  getData(id) {
    const idMod = id
    const idModN = document.getElementById("idMod").innerHTML = idMod
    console.log (idModN)
  }
```

I would like clicking on the button to insert the id of each element of the Json and I would like something like this:

```
<button(click)="getData({{ forecast.id }})">Test</button>
```

but the syntax {{ forecast.id }} inside the brackets when I call the function throws an error. If instead I put any number by hand it works perfectly. How do I make it work with {{ forecast.id }}? I have many ids and would like them to be fetched with the for loop.

Comment: `<button(click)="getData( forecast.id )">Test</button>` try with this. it should work. just remove the parenthesis inside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the `id` inside the `forecast`, you should not use parenthesis, that is not how we pass the parameter in angular.

Inside your Html try to rewrite it like that:

```
<button(click)="getData(forecast.id)">Test</button>
```

Hope that might help